# Using MySQL and PHP to Update Allow IP's in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm building a site in which a text file must be directly accessible using cURL or wget, without authentication, to a changing list of IP addresses with defined expiration dates that can be stored in a database.

The file has to be an actual text file (as in "file.txt"). It has to be directly accessible over the Web as a URI (e.g. "https://example.com/file.txt"). It can't be wrapped in a PHP or HTML page.

So I'm thinking that I have to use .htaccess to restrict access to the directory by IP. There probably will be several dozen IP addresses at any given time.

Question: What's the best way to automate the update of the allowed IP's in .htaccess (that is, remove expired IP addresses and add new ones) every night?

I know I can use PHP and mySQL to simply build a new .htaccess file with the currently-active IP's whenever they change. That actually seems the easiest way. Just write a PHP script that contains all the .htaccess information that doesn't change, pull the active IP's from the db and stick them in there, and file_put_contents as the new .htaccess  file. That seems easy enough. But is there a better way?

Alternatively, is there some other way besides using .htaccess to restrict access to a text file by IP, bearing in mind that the text file has to be a URI?

Thank you.

Comment: `It can't be wrapped in a PHP` why not? Put the file in a non public directory. Direct all requests to unknown files to a php file. Match the ip address with the database and print out the file contents via php.

Comment: Hmmmm... I didn't think of that. That lets me use straight PHP / MySQL for the authentication via IP, but still returns the expected result to the requesting server. The fact that it had to be a text file in the URI threw me off; but all I have to do is stash it elsewhere. Thanks!